# How to start every word in a string with a capital letter except the first?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a sentence and have every word start with a capital letter except the first one and remove the spaces. How do I do this ?

I've looked into the [start:stop:step] method but don't quite understand it that well. I have tried splitting the sentence but also to no avail.

My code till now:

```
sentence = "A String S And A Number N"             
sentence = sentence.title()
sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "")

print(sentence)
```

Expected output: aStringSAndANumberN
Actual output: AStringSAndANumberN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this that uses your existing code is to simply swap out the first character with the result of calling lower() on it:

```
sentence = "A String S And A Number N"             
sentence = sentence.title()
sentence = sentence.replace(" ", "")
sentence = sentence[0].lower() + sentence[1:]

print(sentence)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sometimes you just need an outsider's perspective :)